# How to have the attached file name in Access database

Tags: sql, vba

In Microsoft Access, we can attach files into a column (Datatype: Attachment).

And we can retrieve the FileName using:

```
SELECT Persons.SSN, Persons.Attachment.FileName
FROM Persons;
```

Now we need to keep only the file name (Text) to reduce the total size, which is near to 2GB. I created a column and try to collect FileName with it. Here is the `VBA` code:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Persons " & _
"SET AttachedFilename = Persons.Attachment.FileName " & _
"WHERE Attachment.FileName Is NOT NULL"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```

The error:

```
Run-time error '3061'
Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

If I change it into

```
...
"SET AttachedFilename = 'aaaaa' " & _
...
```

then, the update is processed with no problem.

What is the correct way to do this Update?

Comment: If you only want the file name, do you need a field of type Attachment?

Comment: You have too many quotes don't you?  I don't know vba but shouldn't the whole thing be in one set of quotes?

Comment: I used to have a column typed as attachment. Now I want to only keep the text of the filename.

Comment: Don't you need to join it to the Persons table?  That query wouldn't know what persons.attachment.FileName is.  Access sees it, doesn't see the quotes, so doesn't try to treat it as a string... try adding a FROM clause and "joining" the table to itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a space after `"UPDATE Persons"` should be **`"UPDATE Persons "`**

**EDIT**
just tried on my Access 2007, this is what you need to run

```
UPDATE Persons AS t1 

INNER JOIN (
SELECT ssn, Persons.Attachment.FileName as fn
FROM Persons
) AS t2 

ON t1.ssn = t2.ssn 
SET t1.AttachmentFileName = fn;
```

rather weird you can select ***Persons.Attachment.FileName*** but when you update, it doesn't work